# Create per user workspace in nlplab Brat annotation tool

Tags: nlp, brat

Is it possible to separate users on one Brat server instance? I know how to create new user accounts in the config.py file, but it seems that all users can view all files (in Brat's data directory) through the collection window in the web app.

I need the users to be able only to view files that (somehow) belong to their login. I'm uploading the text and .ann files directly to the data folder, so the users only need to log-in and start annotating.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered a way. You can place an acl.conf file into the desired directory and set some rules:
`User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
User-Agent: testuser
Allow: /`

This restricts the access to the 'testuser' login and displays "access denied" message to other users. It has some disadvantages which are discussed in the [Google User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/brat-users/mMgRQKBAUbs), along with another approach.